# rails compare two urls in different database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Heres my code

```
  def inside
    @events = Newevent.all
    event = @events.where(geturl)
    gmiurl = Gmi.where(merchantdeeplink: event)
    @gmi = !gmiurl
  end
```

So, what i'm trying to do here is to check if the geturl (which is a column in my database table) and compare this to the merchantdeeplink which also has a url. Then only show everything thats doesnt match.

Any help? I can attempt to explain better

Sam

Comment: What instances do you want returned? `Newevent` ? `Gmi` ? or both?

Comment: i need all the results in the Gmi table returned that havent got the geturl field that exists in the Newevent table

Comment: are these two tables related in some way? Meaning does one of them has a foreign key referring to the other table?

Answer (score 0):

Following your design pattern, you could do something like this:

```
  def inside
    @events = Newevent.all
    @gmi = Gmi.all

    @events.each do |event|
      @gmi.select do |item|
       item.merchantdeeplink != event.geturl
      end
    end
  end
```

This isn't the best way of checking if the strings aren't equal (very inefficient). If you're table are joined together somehow you could do this much more efficiently by using a [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and then checking their equality.

**UPDATE**

As @Leito suggested:

```
event_urls = Newevent.pluck(:geturl)
@gmis = Gmi.where.not(merchantdeeplink: event_urls)
```

Comment: How would i go about calling this in the view? so every row is shown in the table?

Comment: Well it depends here. Instead of using a instance method `inside` iI would suggest using a Gmi class method since that's what you are trying to return. You would need to show more code like your controller and your views so I have better context. It's hard to help you with this much information...

Comment: Careful, this is extremely slow! It creates to big arrays and for each element in the first it, potentially iterates over the second array entirely. This should perform better: `event_urls = Newevent.pluck(:geturl); @gmis = Gmi.where.not(merchantdeeplink: event_urls)`. It simply creates an array of the geturls that exists in Newevent and returns all Gmi that don't have any of these urls. That said, naming conventions and overall application design doesn't look good and you should take a step back and rethink this before forcing it.

Comment: Yes correct like I said I was using his design pattern approach